# HTML5/CSS3 Image Rotatation initiated by another Image Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

When you mouse over either image, each rotates 360 degrees and changes from 50% to 100% opacity revealing image text below. I am trying to rotate the opposite image from which I hover over to simulate turning gears.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KalleThomas/BRGG2/29/) here.

```
#navBlueGear {
    float:left;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity:0.5;}

#navBlueGear:hover {
    opacity:1.0;}

#aboutMe {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:130px;
    left:-80px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 1.5s;
    -moz-transition: 1.5s;
    -o-transition: 1.5s;
    transition: 1.5s;}

#navBlueGear:hover ~ #aboutMe {
    opacity: 1;}

.aboutLink {
    -webkit-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    transition:all 1.5s ease-out;}

.aboutLink:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);}

#navOrangeGear {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:85px;
    left:-75px;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity:0.5;}

#navOrangeGear:hover {
    opacity:1.0;}

#work {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top:176px;
    left:-143px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;}

#navOrangeGear:hover ~ #work {
    opacity: 1;}

.workLink {
    -webkit-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 1.5s ease-out;
    transition:all 1.5s ease-out;}

.workLink:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);}
```

Is it possible to turn the opposite gear counter to the image you initially hover over as well as control the speed as the teeth of each need to look realistic?

Is it possible in CSS3 and if not how would I accomplish this in JavaScript? Any other suggestions or advice is appreciated, I am just beginning to work with writing code, thank you in advance.

Comment: If interpret accurately, requirement includes images appearing as gears moving effect ? At jsfiddle at original post, the described effect appear to occur briefly , at certain  on `css` `:hover` positions. Could perhaps place `transform`, `transition` pieces into `css` `animation` , `@keyframe` blocks. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

http://jsfiddle.net/BRGG2/30/

I put all elements in a containing div and set the rotation to work when that div is hovered.
Each gear keeps its own opacity and hover link.

I set the second gear to turn the opposite way using this

```
#container:hover .workLink {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-360deg);
    transform:rotate(-360deg);
}
```

As to calibrate both gears speed, this will take some fine tuning, using `-webkit-transition-duration`.

Comment: The final can be found [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KalleThomas/BRGG2/55/).


Adding the div container was just the solution I was looking for. From there it was about adjusting the rotation of the smaller gear to coincide with the rotation of the larger. The duration was great suggestion but rotating the smaller gear further to =540 degrees synced up perfectly while having them begin, turn, and stop at the same duration looked a lot more clean fluid. Thank you for your help @Gil.